# CodeIgniter flashdata [flash:old:message] being displayed

Tags: codeigniter, flash

I'm using CodeIgniter on OpenShift.

In my controller I'm using:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'message X');  
$this->load->view('viewpage');
```

In my view I'm using:

```
print_r ($this->session->userdata);
echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

Here are my observations:
first time through the controller/load view, I see nothing echoed with the

```
$this->session->flashdata('message');
```

I see this with the print_r:

> [flash:new:message]=>message 1

second time through the controller/load view, I see "message 1" being echoed
I see this with the print_r:

> [flash:old:message] =>message 1[flash:new:message]=>message 2

So what appears to be happening is that [flash:old:message] is being displayed instead of [flash:new:message].  If  [flash:old:message] isn't set, then nothing is displayed.

Please help.

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

when you set a value in a flash data, you need to make a view refresh like:

controller.php

```
function do_somthing(){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('index', 'text message');

    redirect('controller/view', 'refresh');
}
```

controller/view.php

```
<div>
    <?= (isset($this->session->flashdata('index'))) ? $this->session->flashdata('index') : ''?>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much.That seems to work; however, that seems to lose my $_POST data?

Answer (score 0):

Flashdata is designed to be used moving from 1 page to another (redirects), you typically use it after a post, the return a success/failure message.

the reason for this:

> [flash:old:message] =>message 1[flash:new:message]=>message 2

occurring is because flashdata is retained for 1 additional page load (so you can use $this->session->keep_flashdata() if required... as you are triggering flashdata by refreshing the page to generate these results its confusing things and not designed for use this way..

This really seems to be an issue occurring due to the way you are using flashdata than it displaying the incorrect data.

A working example of using flashdata is below (even without a redirect)

controller:

```
    public function index()
{

    if (!$this->input->post()) {

        $this->load->view('playland/index');

    }else{
        if ($this->input->post('submit') == "submit") {

            $data['firstname'] = $this->input->post('firstname');
            $data['lastname'] = $this->input->post('lastname');

            $this->session->set_flashdata('test', 'data posted');

            $this->load->view('playland/retrieve', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

index view:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <?php print_r($this->session->userdata)?>
<form method="post" action="playland">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

retrieve view:

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('test') ?><br>
<p>
    First Name:<br>
    <?php echo isset($firstname) ? $firstname : '';?><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <?php echo isset($lastname) ? $lastname : '';?><br>
</p>
<A HREF="javascript:history.go(0)">Click to refresh the page</A>
<A HREF="javascript:history.back()">Return to original page</A>
</body>
</html>
```